# Predicting the increase/decrease of number

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have these entries in my database that looks like this:

```
ItemID  Number         Time 
14      1.74           "2014-12-21 17:13:29"
14      1.73           "2014-12-21 17:13:30"
78      2.55           "2014-12-21 17:17:11"
78      2.56           "2014-12-21 17:18:12"
```

For each item I have an **entry** for each second for a a period of ~5 minutes. So each item has ~300 data entries. All in all I have thousands of items, therefore lets say 300 000 entries.

I would like to know in average, is there a **tendency** that the **Number** within these 5 minutes will rather drop or increase over all these items and how strong is this **tendency**.

I can see it visually that one items number does fall or increase, but what algorithm should I use to find it out over all of these items?

I am not strong in maths, but I was googling about it, and found out about regression, but not sure how to exactly use it.

Can you give me a hint or suggestion, which algorithm I should use to analyze this data?

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand you correctly, you have ~1000 (300k / 300) unique ItemIDs. For each of these IDs you have ~300 consecutive seconds worth of data.

The obvious solution would be linear regression. That would allow you to ask whether, with each second, there is a statistically reliable increase/decrease in the value of Number. What I would recommend is converting each ItemID's times into the number of seconds since the beginning of the window (so the first time would be 0, the second would be 1, third 2, on and on until ~300 is ~299). You would then see whether the number of seconds since the beginning of the window was a statistically significant predictor of the value of Number.

There are a couple of caveats here. The regression will make several assumptions about your data. The first is independence of the observations (strictly speaking, independence of the errors, but I'd rather not complicate matters). In effect, all of the ItemID 14's observations are related to each other in a way that they're not related to ItemID 78's observations.

In order to ensure this assumption is met, you'll need to model this non-independence. To do so, you'll probably want to look into mixed effects models. To help with the terminology, ItemID is your random effect, time since the beginning of the window is your fixed effect.

Another assumption is that there is a linear relationship between time and Number. If that's not the case (plot Number against time) then you might need to look into polynomial (or other non-linear) regression.

In terms of what you might need. lme() in the nlme package and lmer() in the lme4 package for R will both allow you to fit the mixed effects model.

This will tell you if there is a tendency. Assessing the strength of the tendency is a different matter. You might want to investigate Effects size.